# Signals and Variables in VHDL

Tags: variables, signals, vhdl

I want to ask about the signals and variables in VHDL, I know the difference between them, but I want to see the difference at simulation.

I used this simple program in Quartus Tool to see the difference between them:

```
ENTITY test IS PORT (
  a : IN bit;
  y : OUT bit);
END test;

ARCHITECTURE beh OF test IS
SIGNAL x : BIT;
BEGIN
  PROCESS (a)
  BEGIN
    x <= '1';
    IF x = '1' THEN y <= '0' AFTER 8 ns;
    ELSE y <= '1' AFTER 5 ns;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
END BEH;
```

for signals and this for variables:

```
entity test1 is port (
  a : IN bit;
  y : OUT bit);
end test1;

architecture beh of test1 is
begin
  process (a)
  variable x : bit;
  begin
    x := '1';
    if x = '1' then y <= '0' after 8 ns;
    else y <= '1' after 5 ns;
    end if;
  end process;
end beh;
```

the i created waveform to see the difference in the first program `(y)value` should be set to `1` at `5ns`,but it doesn't change..Why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should post the code of your testbench as well, so we can see what you actually simulated.

Comment: @ damage:i want to see the difference between signals and variables at simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the difference in waveforms, as the waveform viewer only shows the values of variables at the end of a delta cycle (ie when some real time passes).  If you single-step the code, or add `report` statements mid process, you can see intermediate values on a variable:

```
signal s:integer := 0;
process
   variable v:integer := 0;
begin
   report "Signal="&integer'image(s)&" variable="&integer'image(v);
   s <= 1; v := 1;
   report "Signal="&integer'image(s)&" variable="&integer'image(v);
   wait for 0 ps; -- end the delta cycle, even 0ps counts as "time passing"
   report "Signal="&integer'image(s)&" variable="&integer'image(v);
   wait;
end process;
```

Answer (score 0):

You put signal "a" on sensitive list then it lead to a "latch".

For update y, you should put "x" on sensitive list or change "a" like a trigger signal.

In your case, signal and variable is similar because you fixed it as a constant.

For addition, you should upload your testbench with behaviour of signal "a".

---

**Edit: I'm wrong about put "x" in sensitive list. Thanks to @damage**

Comment: remember there is an assignment to signal x inside the process(first example). putting x on the sensitivity list without further changes will require an event on x(some assignment to x, not taking into account the initial run of the process at simulation startup) in order to trigger the process. this could lead to a situation where x has multiple drivers, one inside the process and one outside the process(for triggering purposes).

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should illustrate the difference b/w signals and variables.
I inserted the processes directly into the testbench, so the code can be directly simulated with a HDL simulator of your choice.
After 10 ns the `start` event is fired and both processes are evaluated.
You should then see the expected result, namely `sig_out`going high after another 20 ns, whereas `var_out` should be high after only 10 ns.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sigvartest is
end entity sigvartest;

architecture behav of sigvartest is

signal start : std_logic := '0'; -- event to start simulation

signal x_sig : std_logic := '0'; -- signal tested in SIGPROCESS

signal sig_out : std_logic := '0'; -- output of SIGPROCESS

signal var_out : std_logic := '0'; -- output of VARPROCESS

begin

start <= '0', '1' after 10 ns; -- pretty self-explanatory, start goes high after 10 ns

SIGPROCESS:
        process(start) is
        begin
            if(rising_edge(start)) then
                x_sig <= '1'; -- signal is scheduled to be assigned its new value, no immediate change!

                if(x_sig = '1') then
                    sig_out <= '1' after 10 ns;
                else
                    sig_out <= '1' after 20 ns; -- this part will execute
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

VARPROCESS:
        process(start) is
                variable x_var : std_logic := '0';
        begin
                if(rising_edge(start)) then
                    x_var := '1'; -- variable is assigned immediately

                    if(x_var = '1') then
                        var_out <= '1' after 10 ns;  -- this part will execute
                    else
                        var_out <= '1' after 20 ns;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: :Thank you very much for your help,but i don't use TestBenchm i used waveform in quartus to see the difference but it wasn't clear; can i see the difference using waveform simulation??